# Jupyter interactive 3D plot of several planes in a volume

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to display several 2D arrays or dataframes as contour plots in a single 3D axes object?

The arrays represent planes in a volume, and each element stands for a data point.

I'd be happy enough if this is possible for a simple stack, i.e. with the planes spaced by some value z, and the x and y corrodinate is given as the index and column of the dataframe, for example. Some level of transparency would be necessary to "look through" the stack.

As an even more advanced version, the planes have different orientation, some are x-y planes, others x-z planes.

Plotly seems a good and fast enough toolkit, but I am open for everything.